# Can you Recover Data from a Filevault encrypted harddrive externally?

Tags: hard-drive, filevault

My mac won't boot and it maybe a harddrive issue, but I need to get the data off it, is it possible to recover the data using a set of tools if I know the password and have the appropriate cables?

Comment: Yes, it cannot find the harddisk. It doesnt show up

Comment: cmd+r should connect to the internet if it doesn't find a disk. What Mac do you have?

Answer (score 1):

What Mac are you using (Macbook Air / Pro)? Does it have a replaceable disk?

If the disk is not replaceable, I see the following options:

- Access your Mac in [target mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1661) and unlock the disk from another computer. For example [this article](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/using-disk-utility-to-unlock-or-decrypt-your-filevault-2-encrypted-boot-drive/) explains the procedure.
- Using recovery mode: Press `cmd + R` : [Recovery Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4811)
- Same as above, but you [manually select](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1310) the recovery partition by pressing `alt` at boot

Sometimes the filevault2 volume cannot be opened easily. See [here](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/mac-os-x-10-8-4s-recovery-hd-removes-ability-to-decrypt-filevault-2-encrypted-mac/) for a workaround.

If the disk is replaceable I would remove it, unlock the disk, and save the data e.g. with an USB-IDE adapter (like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812232002) one).